# How can I make SVG text editable?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a text tag that I'm adding to SVG via JS script and would like to make that text editable.

Found a couple of solutions on StackOverflow:

1. creating a css class and applying it to my SVG text element. This works perfectly, at least in Safari, but isn't recommended it by MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-modify
   Here is the class that is actually someone's answer, unfortunately I can't remember whose:

   ```
   .editable {
       font-size: 0.3em;
       user-modify: read-write;
       -moz-user-modify: read-write;
       -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
   }
   ```
2. wrapping the svg in a contenteditable div (answer given by Erik). This also works but results in bad cursor behavior, at least in Safari.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <svg id="svgArea" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  </svg>
</div>
```

The JS part

```
function foo(x, y, w, h) {
  var rect, group;
  var svgPlace = document.getElementById('svgArea');
  var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  group = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'g');
  svgPlace.appendChild(group);

  var txtElem = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'text');
  txtElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
  txtElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y * 1.25);
  txtElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'LightBlue');
  txtElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'contentEditable', true); //does nothing!
  txtElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'editable'); //this is the best working option at the moment
  var txtVal = document.createTextNode('test');
  txtElem.appendChild(txtVal);
  group.appendChild(txtElem);
}
```

I'd love to be able to set the contentEditable as an attribute, if that's possible. But most importantly, what's the best way to make SVG text editable?

Comment: `document.getElementById("element").contentEditable = "true";` You can also use the ref `contenteditable="true"` in an HTML element like so: `<div contenteditable="true">`.

Comment: In your second example, you have no text element to edit..

Comment: Raymond, The <div contenteditable="true"> wrapped around <svg> works but produces odd cursor behavior. I can't get setting contentEditable  to 'true' to work. This is what I tried, am I doing it wrong?: document.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].contentEditable='true'

Comment: The text element is added via JS to the SVG element in the second code part.

Answer (score 2):

@Raymond comment is the correct answer but since you still have problem I wrote down an example.

```js
document.getElementById("svgWrapper").contentEditable = "true";
```

```html
<div id="svgWrapper">
  <svg id="svgArea" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Masoud and everyone. That answer is already on StackOverflow and is listed in my question as one of possible solutions. It produces odd cursor behavior. Looking for another way, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by placing an input tag inside a foreign object, which is added to an SVG group. That works on Safari so I wanted to post it here, in case anyone else is struggling with the same thing.

```
<svg>
<g>
<foreignobject>
<input></input>
</foreignobject>
</g>
</svg>
```

If you need to add using JS:

```
function addSvg(x, y, w, h) {
var rect, group;
var svgPlace = document.getElementById('svgArea');
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
group = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'g');
svgPlace.appendChild(group);

// solution
let foreigner = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "foreignObject");
foreigner.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
foreigner.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
foreigner.setAttributeNS(null, "width", w);
foreigner.setAttributeNS(null, "height", h);
group.appendChild(foreigner);

let txt = document.createElement('input');
foreigner.appendChild(txt);
```

}